# Rails - Dropdown changing multiple input fields?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking for a ruby on rails example of a drop down that will change a bunch of input fields. In short I have three people you can be... You choose this from a drop down, and for each of those three people, they have five of their own questions each.

Do you know of any examples out there of something like this that I could learn from?

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you selecting from a dropdown, submitting, and returning a response with the unique question set based on the user's selection?

Comment: @Vardarac - First, thanks for following up! Second, my goal was to return the response (five inputs) on the same page after the user's selection without having to submit.

Comment: This might be doable using only Rails helpers, but it will likely be easier if you know and are okay with using jQuery. What's your preference?

Comment: @Vardarac jQuery would be the preference honestly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I envision it. In your view:

```
<%= select_tag :person_id,
    options_from_collection_for_select(Person.all, "id", "name", person_to_prepopulate_select_with),
    :id => "person_selector_for_questions" %>
```

This creates your dropdown. I'm assuming that you have a `Person` model, and that a `Person` `has_many` `Question`s.

In your JavaScript:

```
$("#person_selector_for_questions").change(function(e) {
    var $dropdown = $(this);
    $.get('/questions?person_id=' + $dropdown.val(), function(data) {
         $dropdown.after(data);
    });
});
```

This (1) fires a jQuery event handler when the user changes the value of the dropdown, (2) fires an AJAX GET request to `http://yoursite/questions?person_id=selected_person_id`, and (3) sticks the response it gets into the current page following your dropdown using `.after`. You can of course customize your jQuery calls to place this in the page where you need it.

Now the important part. In your `QuestionsController`:

```
def index
  if request.xhr? && params[:person_id]
    @questions = Question.where(:person_id => params[:person_id]
    render :person_questions
    return # important to prevent rest of controller action from firing
  end
end
```

This primes the `index` action to deal with AJAX calls containing person_ids in their query string. It will fire back a partial named `person_questions` from the views folder corresponding to the controller (in this case the `questions` folder), which will contain the information you want stuck into your webpage.

Finally, you must create this partial, `_person_questions.html.erb` in your `app/views/questions` folder. This partial will contain what jQuery will stick in your page. You could, for example, put this in the partial:

```
<% @questions.each do |q| %>
    <%= q.contents %>
<% end %>
```

Thus the question contents, or whatever else your heart desires to be placed on the page, is loaded into the current page.

Comment: Trying this out now but this makes so much more sense! Thanks @Vardarc

Comment: By the way, worked perfectly! Thank you so much... Now we are playing with the drop down 'replacing' the original code with JS. This was so helpful by the way.